# How to restrict PDF file with malicious content?

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, pdf, pdftron

I am facing an issue with PDF validation, I have a pdf with javascript code in it

```
%PDF-1.0

1 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Pages 2 0 R
/Names 6 0 R
>>
endobj

2 0 obj
<<
/Type /Pages
/Count 1
/Kids [3 0 R]
>>
endobj

3 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Parent 2 0 R
/Resources << /Font << /F1 5 0 R >>
>>
/MediaBox [0 0 612 792]
/Contents 4 0 R
>>
endobj

4 0 obj
<< /Length 45 >>
stream
BT
/F1 24 Tf
250 700 Td (Hello, World!) Tj
ET
endstream
endobj

5 0 obj
<<
/Type /Font
/Subtype /Type1
/BaseFont /Helvetica
>>
endobj

6 0 obj
<<
/JavaScript 7 0 R
>>
endobj

7 0 obj
<<
/Names [(My Code) 8 0 R]
>>
endobj

8 0 obj
<<
/JS (app.alert({cMsg: document.location,
cTitle: "Mario's Message"});
)
/S /JavaScript
>>
endobj

xref
0 9

trailer
<<
/Size 9
/Root 1 0 R
>>
startxref

%%EOF
```

how can I restrict this type of PDF files from uploading?

**I am using reactJS in Front-end, java in Back-end, and using PDFTron web SDK to load PDF on browser.**

Can I restrict this on Front-end by checking the content of the file or Can I check the content of the PDF file on back-end?

What is the best way to restrict PDF file with malicious content?

Comment: Checking on the front end is no use, as someone can always upload to your endpoint directly.

Comment: You'll need a decent PDF library tool on the backend since JavaScript can be attached to just about any interactive document element in a PDF.

Comment: You can certainly use PDFTron SDK client side to detect javascript in the PDF (or also on server side). Though as pointed above, you have to check the entire PDF, and also requires loading the larger "Full" version of PDFNetJS for this low level parsing. To clarify, your objective is to stop users from knowingly or unknowingly uploading PDF files with any sort of JS at all?

Comment: 1st:- I want to block users to upload malicious PDF (If I can) 2nd if not than need help from PDFTron to block this PDF while showing on browser with some error massage.